# Determine time complexity of program based on its runtime

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity

I'm looking for a way to determine the time complexity of a program based of its runtime.

I have plotted my results for different sizes of n and now looking for a way to determine the constants c and n0 so that f(n) ≤ c*(g(n)) for every n ≥ n0.

About the program:

> Input: n, number of elements
>
> Output: running time

All steps in measuring the data have been done 100 times to get an average runtime for the program.

Some example values for different sizes of n:

> n……………runtime(ms)
>
> 1000……….1,6
>
> 10 000……..222,8
>
> 100 000……25213

Help much appreciated!

pepefatha

Comment: You would do better to sample at 300 values of n rather than averaging the results of 100 runs at only 3 values.  Then run it through a stats package and see what order regression model gives you a decent fit.  Regression will also give you an estimate of the intercept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need more data points to be sure. But it looks like multiplying your n by 10, approximately multiplies your runtime by 100, so n^2 would be my guess.

As for the constant, you just need plot it on a log scale and find the intercept (extrapolated from the largest values, i.e. those greater than the value of `n0`) with the y axis, which will be log(c).

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages have constant-time functions that obtain the current time.  You can time the program by putting in the time difference between the end and beginning of the program and plot these times for different sizes of n.